# LaTeX, overleaf, page number inconsistenecy

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, overleaf

the second page of my table of contents has the page number in the top right corner when everywhere else it's in the bottom middle- it also repeates the contents title in italics and so it looks like another line in the toc - how do I fox this so that there is no 'contents' title and the page number is the same as all the other pages?
[![picture of pdf output][1]][1]

````
%\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite} % apa citation
\usepackage{amssymb} %symbols
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{setspace}
%\singlespacing
%\onehalfspacing
\doublespacing


\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\RequirePackage{apacite}
\let\cite\shortcite
\let\citeA\shortciteA

\begin{document}    % BEGINING OF DOCUMENT

\pagenumbering{roman}

\input{title}
%\frontmatter %makes preface sections i, ii,... 

\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
summary

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
saying thank you

\tableofcontents
%\mainmatter % makes chapter sections numbered (1, 2, 3)
\newpage

\listoftables
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{listofftables}
\newpage
\listoffigures
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{listofffigures}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{ch1}
\include{ch2}
\include{ch3}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXj0x.png
````

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which document class you use? What youz describe is pretty standard page layout design ,,,

Comment: HI! I've never used this system before but I think I'm using book template? I've seen other templates that have it at the top but aesthetically I dislike it - if it's the norm though I guess it can't be changed? and thank you!

Comment: I suggest you to read some introductory text About LaTeX. For example https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf. Zhan you should decided which document class you will use and what design of page layout you like to have. If default setting by document class no provide what you after, than see `fancyhead` package.